# How can I change the Bootstrap navbar's dropdown caret icon WITHOUT using 'font awesome'?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, navbar, font-awesome, caret

I have read several posts on stack overflow around how to remove the default icon via CSS by way of setting `dropdown-toggle::after` to `display: none`, and then using an `<i>` tag within the HTML to place a fontawesome icon within the navbar, like so -

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

My question is - is it possible to use a standard HTML character - the **plus** symbol - as my caret? i have tried to implement this within the CSS by creating a new class and setting the CSS content like so -

```
.navigation-caret-plus-symbol {
    content:"\002B";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

I cannot seem to get this working, though. The font awesome solution would be fine only the available font within their typeface only exists at a weight of 900, which is far too heavy.

I have also tried creating a CSS class which uses a background image, then setting this using a span or the HTML `<i>` tag within the navbar, but sadly this does not display anything.

Comment: Does my [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65981447/3113485) work for you?

Comment: This can not be verified as yet. If it can be verified it will be upvoted and/or marked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is:

> [I]s it possible to use a standard HTML character - the plus symbol - as my caret?

Yes.

This new CSS rule will replace the default dropdown "▾" with a "+" character.

```css
.dropdown-toggle.dropdown-plus::after {
  vertical-align: 0;
  margin: 0;
  content: "\002B";
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.6.0 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      
        <!-- add "dropdown-plus" to dropdown link to change "▾" to "+" -->
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-plus" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <!-- -->
        
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```